# SSIS Package Migration from 2008R2 to 2016 version

Tags: ssis

I am upgrading SSIS packages created and running in 2008R2 to 2016 version.
Facing various issue where ever there is a script task inside a package.

Can anyone help me with any generic way to upgrade script tasks like upgrading assemblies or libraries in it ? 
or 
Do I have to pitch into each script and make changes individually inside ?

Tried upgrading the assemblies in one of the script task, the cross sign dissappeared however, there were still some errors in the script related to few classes.

Comment: We had this issue upgrading from 2012 to 2016.  We just had to go into and recompile every Script task.  Some had more advanced issues but this solved most.  Also we had some issues when calling Stored Procedures (if you are doing this) we had to add WITH RESULTET to the SP call.

Comment: I had to do the same thing Brad did when upgrading from 2008R2 to 2012. I think the underlying .NET level changed therefore changing the targets until you opened and closed it

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Will try and implement it and let you guys know